# assign a value from a list to corresponding string on terminal

Tags: bash, awk, command-line, extract, carriage-return

I am trying to do create a list with assigning the corresponding values from another list.

I have a file like this(list.txt);

```
.
.
ak_1002
ak_1002
ak_1014
ak_1017
ak_1017 
ak_1239
ak_1246
ak_1284
ak_1286
ak_1320
ak_138
ak_139
.
.
```

And another file with the corresponding values (ref.txt)

```
.
.
ak_1     39,877
ak_10    75,636
ak_100   32,936
ak_1000  81,609
ak_1002  30,946
ak_1003  40,862
ak_1004  96,566
ak_1005  50,778
ak_1006  62,698
ak_1007  47,8
ak_1008  37,895
ak_1009  126,501
ak_101   45,829
ak_1011  33,925
ak_1012  50,778
ak_1013  43,842
ak_1014  65,676
ak_1015  161,859
ak_1016  70,652
ak_1017  32,933
.
.
```

I am trying to obtain a result file should be looking like this:

```
.
.
ak_1002 30,946
ak_1002 30,946
ak_1014 65,676
ak_1017 32,933
ak_1017 32,933 
.
.
```

Actually, I was using this code with other datasets and it was working perfectly, but right now it is returning no result.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ arr[NR]=$0 }
    NR!=FNR{ for(i in arr){
      if(arr[i]==$1){ print arr[i],$2 } } }' list.txt ref.txt > result.txt
```

PS: I am sure that there is only one corresponding value to every unique string, and also sure that all of the strings in the list.txt exist in ref.txt, because list.txt is a subset of ref.txt.

I could not figure out the reason. If you have any idea thank you in advance.

Comment: Show output of this command: `file list.txt ref.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus list.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
ref.txt:  CSV text

Comment: I suggest to convert list.txt to ASCII text.

Comment: what to do with an entry from `list.txt` that does not have a match in `ref.txt`? for a given entry in `list.txt` can there be more than 1 match in `ref.txt`, and if so then which entry from `ref.txt` should be used? please update the question with your answers/additional details

Comment: Get rid of all the spurious `.`s from your example and simply provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input that covers all of your use cases (especially any rainy day ones) and the exact output you expect given that input so we have something we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: @Cyrus Apparently, my problem was not with the code but with the format, I fixed it and obtained desired results. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`join`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) command:

```sh
join list.txt ref.txt
```

```
ak_1002 30,946
ak_1002 30,946
ak_1014 65,676
ak_1017 32,933
ak_1017 32,933
```

---

**Update:** handling `CRLF` line endings in `list.txt`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

join <(sed $'s/\r$//' list.txt) ref.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk,

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' 'FNR==NR{ arr[$1]=$2 }
     FNR!=NR{ if ($1 in arr) print $1, arr[$1]; }' ref.txt list.txt
```

Comment: `'\n|\r\n'` = `'\r?\n'` (slightly briefer and no repeated characters) and you should mention in your answer it requires GNU awk for multi-char RS.